# Parallel-In-Serial-Out with Parity?

Tags: shift-register, crc, parity

Can someone recommend a shift register IC with integrated parity or CRC generator? Is there such a thing anyway?

Comment: There probably was.  It shouldn't take too much logic, so if you get stuck or have sourcing trouble, CPLD's are cheap.  Depending on your speed needs, a microcontroller might even be able to do it.

Comment: I would like to avoid another programmable part on what should be a simple extension board

Comment: You mean like a UART?

Answer (score 1):

I would clock the byte into a Parity Generator, then clock the output of that into a 9 bit Parallel-In-Serial-Out shift register, and shift away...

Sure, it's two chips, but it's better than a programmable part.

74HC280 and 
SY10E142

Or equivalents.

Comment: I expected that a combined part would exist... I will check out the parts.

Comment: It does exist - it's called a microcontroller or CPLD :P